# Is there a way to run same command in every input in csh?

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

For example: 
I want to run

```
echo a
echo b
echo c
echo d
```

but with only

```
a
b
c
d
```

is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, what's your **exact** purpose here? Are you trying to *type in* `a`  to *execute* `echo a`?

Comment: yes but not only to a. I want to type whatever input but when execute prefix with certain command. such as echo.

Comment: Yes, I kind of get your point. What's your real problem, is it possible you provide it? There are many ways to solve it but it depends on your exact problem, I suppose.

Comment: Well, I am using taskwarrior, and I want to use teskwarrior without type task every time, but I don't want to use alias to solve the problem(since I do not want to source some alias file every time, and we need to run certain task on the server which will copy our local setting for running, I certainly do not want my personal setting get copied and we dont have sudo permission since its our company server)

Comment: It's much clearer now, would you just elaborate your question based on your comments? Thanks for the details.